# Difference between int *x[10] and int (*x)[10]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Last time we had a test in programming and one of the questions was the difference between initializing

```
int *x[10];
```

and

```
int (*x)[10];
```

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: Check out [C Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: @Joshua: What are these "`*x[10]` and `(*x)[10]`" supposed to be? Declarators or expressions? Your question is ambiguous and does not allow for a specific answer until this ambiguity is resolved.

Comment: ah I forgot to point out that it's declarators. int *x[10] and int (*x)[10].

Comment: @Austin Brunkhorst: If these are declarators, as OP confirmed, then operators have nothing to do with it. These tokens are not operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Type *x[10];
```

defines `x` as an array of 10 pointers to `Type`. So `x` itself is an array that contains pointers to `Type`. On the other hand,

```
Type (*x)[10];
```

defines `x` as a pointer to array-10 of `Type`. Hence `x` points to the befinning of an array of size 10, and the array contains objects of type `Type`. See [this](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) for a great introduction to how to read complicated declarations in C, and also try [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*x%29%5B10%5D).

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find anything that explains the difference thoroughly. This answered my question.

Comment: @Joshua You're welcome, glad it helped.

Comment: So in essence Type (*x)[10]; is the same as x[10]; ??

Comment: @user2419083 No. When you increment `x` in the first case, it "jumps" over 10 elements, as it points to an array. So think of the array as a contiguous area of storage, of size `10*sizeof(Type)`. In the second case, `x` points to the beginning of the array, and incrementing it results in "jumping" over 1 element. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Added bit: `sizeof (int *x[10])`  is the size of 10* `int`.  `sizeof (int (*x)[10]` is the size of a single pointer.

Comment: @chux Small typo: `sizeof (int *x[10])` is the size of **`10* sizeof(int*)`**